# Построение SaaS системы - архитектура БД

Tags: php, sql

Планирую писать ИМ (интернет магазин). Модель магазина будет не коробочной, а SaaS. Среда разработки - php.
На данный момент тщательно продумываю всю техническую и функциональную сторону разработки.
Передо мной встал вопрос относительно архитектуры данных в бд. Какой из двух приведенных мной ниже вариантов является наиболее оптимальным?

1) Много бд (одна на каждого пользователя).

Плюсы:

- производительность не падает;
- скорость доступа к данным не снижается;

Минусы:

- бывает не удобным администрировать;
- применение больше 5 бд является затратным ;

2) Одна бд (на всех пользователей).

Плюсы:

- дешевое применения;
- удобство производить операции с бд;
- удобно администрировать;

Минусы:

- много таблиц;
- элемент списка;
- со временем производительность сильно падает;
- скорость доступа к получаемым данным снижается;

Может быть, кто-нибудь поделится собственным мнением по данному поводу и опишет, почему тот или иной вариант лучше или хуже, либо предложит альтернативу или дополнит по недостающим пунктам. В принципе все построение полей и таблиц я продумал, осталось только разобраться с количеством использования БД. Изначально может показаться, что одной базы достаточно, но ведь нужно предусмотреть все ситуации.

P.S. Информацию о мультитенантности SaaS и о способах построения архитектуры БД читал в открытых источниках, но опять же, здесь все неоднозначно, и хотелось бы услышать как можно больше мнений по данному поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначно для каждого пользователя своя БД.

1. Удобно администрировать. Вы всегда знаете, в какой базе лежат данные какого пользователя. Для удаления/переноса тоже удобней. Также при разрастании БД можно разносить отдельные базы на разные сервера.
2. Безопасность. При единой базе, взломав одного пользователя, получают доступ ко всем.
3. Затратность по средствам? Вы на виртуальном хостинге что ли собираетесь размещать систему? Только отдельный сервер (для начала хотя бы VDS), на котором никто, кроме Вас, не будет устанавливать лимиты на количество создаваемых БД.

ИМХО.

Comment: Я не спец в SaaS, но предпочел бы сначала одну бд, а потом, если будет надобно, разнести по разным не сложно будет, думаю...

Comment: terantul, спасибо за ответ. Думаю, что так и поступлю. Использование одной базы меня тоже несколько смущает.

namak7, проблема заключается в том, что если изначально делать одну бд, то все таблицы будут вперемешку в этой бд и это будет, скажем так, немного трудновато с переносом в другую бд, а точней время-затратно. А таблиц на одного пользователя получается будет приблизительно около 5-6 штук.

Comment: @condor, а что у вас для каждого пользователя будет различная структура бд? Тогда вообще нет смысла в вашем вопросе, ибо 1 магазин = 1 бд.
Я изначально подразумевал единую структуру бд...

Comment: @namak7, уже не раз убеждался на практике, что лучше делать систему с учётом роста. Особенно если рост стоит как цель.

Comment: @namak7, структура бд будет одинаковая у всех пользователей. То есть, таблицы во всех бд будут одни и те же, например: users, goods, cats_goods и т.д. Но вноситься ведь в разные бд будут разные данные, разных магазинов совершенно разных пользователей. SaaS подразумевает собой единицу установленной копии продукта на один сервер, а не много копий управления контентом на каждого пользователя (коробочная версия).

Comment: @terantul, я тоже приверженец того, чтобы прежде что-нибудь начинать делать необходимо все тщательно продумать и уж тем более это касается роста пользования той или иной продукции. Следует еще учитывать, что эту систему я буду разрабатывать не один год и даже не два, все силы и ресурсы будут направлены на получение определенного результата.

Comment: @condor, я думаю, если вы знаете все то, что написали, то для вас не составит труда в одной бд хранить данные различных магазинов и не путаться в них)